# One query to select a record from table A that has both options in the relationship table B

Tags: mysql, sql

I feel like I'm thinking about this two hard and the solution should be easier, maybe its just one of those days.

but I have a 3 tables

**product**

```
productId    name    
-----------------
1            the
2            name
3            does't
4            matter
```

**option**

```
optionId    name    
-----------------
1            the
2            name
3            does't
4            matter
```

**product_option**

```
id   productId  optionId  
-------------------------
1    1          1
1    1          3
1    2          4
1    2          1
1    3          1
```

I want to check if productId 1 has optionId 1 and optionId 3 (in this case true), is this doable in a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT P.productId, P.name 
  FROM product AS P 
 WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
              FROM product_option AS PO 
             INNER 
              JOIN option AS O 
                ON PO.optionId = O.optionId 
               AND PO.productId = P.productId 
               AND O.name IN ('value1', 'value2'));
```

Comment: Good answer:)  I was on the same path but had it overengineered into a UDF.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT p.productId
    FROM product p
        INNER JOIN product_option po
            ON p.productId = po.productId
                AND po.optionId IN (1,3)
    GROUP BY p.productId
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT po.optionId) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

first blush, try something like

```
Select po1.Id
from Product_Option po1
inner join Product_Option po2 
  on po1.productId = po2.productId 
  and po1.optionId != po2.productId
where po1.optionId = 1
and po2.optionId = 3
```

That may not be quite what you need, but it's where I would start.  Especially if this is an ad-hoc (or infrequently used) query.